# get error while using java.sql.Connection

Tags: jsp

I am trying to work with my DB using JSP, i am new all around JSP but i am familiar with JAVA langauge. i get the follwoing error for the follwowing code:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- java.sql.Connection cannot be resolved to a 
 variable
```

this is the code:

```
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.sql.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Login check</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    java.sql.Connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jspexample", "root", "");
%>

</body>
</html>
```

and as you can see in the image i add the jar of the jdbc connector:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found there is a bug in the IDE, so i try to compile it and everything is just working good.